Movie from late 80s or early 90s about two brothers who rob a bank
The movie was about two brothers who robb a bank at night. But they are surprised by the sheriff. They kill him, and kidnap his niece who was in his car. They hide out at a cabin in the woods. She eventually falls for one of the brothers. When they are found, one brother is killed and the other escapes. The
girl is rescued. Months later, the remaining brother finds the girl, and wants to kill her, but she tells him she's pregnant with his brother's child.
Can you help me identify this movie?

Welcome to Movies&TV. This question currently lacks plot details. Do you remember language, country or other plot details, any at all? Add them so that it can help identify this movie. Besides, you might wanna give a more descriptive title. Also see How to ask Identify-this-X questions.

It sounds like Slate, Wyn & Me (1987)

When a bank robbery leads to the death of a police officer, Wyn (Simon
  Burke) and Slate (Martin Sacks) Jackson take witness Blanche McBride
  (Sigrid Thornton) hostage and attempt to evade capture. However, when
  the brothers begin to become enamored of their victim, their getaway
  becomes much more complicated.

Wikipedia
/ IMDB / rottentomatoes





Trailer: Youtube
